# How to make Fiddler listen to all IPs

Tags: fiddler

I'm having trouble with one server sending data to another server, so I thought: let's debug it. I can setup a proxy, so why not use Fiddler? So I made the server use fiddler running on my computer, by setting the host to my computer's IP (192.168.2.111) and the port to 8888.

The problem is that fiddler is listening to localhost:8888 or 127.0.0.1:8888. Therefore, if the request is to 192.168.2.111:8888, the connection is actively refused.

Can I make fiddler listen to ALL IPs?

Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The proper fix is to simply click "Allow remote computers to connect" checkbox inside Tools / Fiddler Options.

Comment: You are right. I don't see how I missed it... It might have been because it had to chain to an upstream gateway proxy, which didn't work because I didn't check "Capture Traffic". Thanks!

Comment: This doesn't work for me on Ubuntu 16.04 and Fiddler v4.6.20171.26113. It still binds only to 127.0.0.1

Comment: It's possible that Linux's implementation is incorrect. Please file a bug with Telerik: https://fiddler.ideas.aha.io

Answer (score 1):

It took a lot of "Reflectoring" and I should have looked in the registry in the first place, but the solution is:

Change HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Fiddler2\AllowRemote to "True".

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if that's possible. Can't you install fiddler directly on the server?