# Make Fiddler accessible by machine hostname

Tags: windows, networking, proxy, localhost, fiddler

I have Telerik Fiddler on port 8888 running on Win 10 machine and I can access it by `http://localhost:8888/` I am seeing `Fiddler Echo Service` screen. But I cannot access fiddler by hostname `http://mymachinehostname:8888/`.

Is it configurable to turn on hostname access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> "Allow remote computers to connect" checkbox inside Tools / Fiddler
>   Options

from [original answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1564235/3014866)